# SQL Workbench Crashing with SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Each time I try to execute a SELECT statement (either manually or through the Workbench IDE), the app crashes.

I am running a MacBook Pro M2 2022. Mac OS Ventura Version 13.0.1 (22A400).

The error is the following:
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [56630]

I tried downloading both the latest version MySql and workbench and older versions from archives. I tried multiple blogs and videos online but none worked.

Workbench 8.0.32
MySql 8.0.32 ARM64, 8.0.32 x64, 8.0.16 x64

Comment: sounds like a bug you should report to the maintainers. I doubt you will find an answer here.

Comment: Already reported (many times) here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102284 I suggest you log into your MySQL Bugs account and click "Affects Me" for that bug.